# Backup of Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is it possible to keep backup of docker images?

Here is my docker image:

```
my@onl-dev:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
centdemo                     latest              e0b0d89f6c45        2 days ago          3.322 GB
```

I have some data in this docker image which I copy from container to host whenever needed.

```
root@onl-dev:/distros/centos6.6.x86_64# docker cp 9512b894d107:/distros/centos6.6.x86_64 /data/sept15/mess
```

So I want to keep backup of this docker image such that I can restore it whenever I want to copy the data from container to host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply tag the image with different tag

```
docker tag <image-name>:latest <image-name>:backup
```

Nonetheless you can always use the image ID: e0b0d89f6c45

Another option is to store it in a tar.

```
docker save mynewimage > /tmp/mynewimage.tar
```